# DoIt Java Style

Tags: code-golf, string

Given string X, convert it to Java Style string, as defined below:

- Strings may only contain numbers and letters(signs are not allowed)
- Strings must not start with numbers
- Strings must start with Capital letter
- Strings may not contain two capital letters in a raw.

As for conversion you may perform the next actions

- Replace capital letter with lower case letter and vise versa.
- Remove character

A good conversion is defined as follow:

Minimum actions been performed while achieving the next goals:

- all the sequences of capital letters only kept the first letter as capital.
- if a letter has a character in place before it, and the character is not a letter nor a number, then the letter becomes capital.
- in case that after a good conversion there is a contradiction with the style, good conversion will be applied again on the result of previous conversion.
- If there is more then one way to apply good conversion, than conversion `A` is considered to be better then conversion `B` if conversion `A` has more capital letters then `B`.

**Input:**

- String x

**Output:**

- Best conversion Java Style String

**I/O examples**

```
X                Output

'ab<>c'          'AbC'
'a<>b<>c'        'Abc' // conversion been applied twice. ABC -> Abc
'a<>bc'          'Abc' // conversion been applied twice. ABc -> Abc
'HI<>man'        'HiMan'
''               ''
'its**cOOL'      'ItsCool'
'28and*2fun'     'And2fun' // conversion been applied twice. and2fun -> And2fun
```

In this example strings been wrapped with '' sign.

**Criteria**

- The shortest program wins, as determined by the number of bytes of source code.

Comment: What about underscores? Java allows underscores in names.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Yes, but `AbC` does not contain two capitals in a row.

Comment: @Doorknob i was afraid it will be to confusing so I did not allow it. My definition is to fallow.

Comment: Would `28and*2Fun` (note the capital `F`) become `And2Fun`? Also would `its**coOL` (one lowercase `o`) become `ItsCoOl`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner yes for both of them

Comment: Without more detail about the interactions between the rules, they seem to contradict each other and some of the test cases. E.g. 'minimum actions been performed' would imply that no letter should be converted to a capital except the first one (required for conformance with the rules for valid output). May I point you at the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/194)?

Comment: Isn't `HI<>man` supposed to be `HiMaN` instead of `HiMan`

Comment: @CoolGuy no, there is no reason to convert the last latter to capital.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I edit it, so now there is no more contradictions

Comment: We can infer from your examples that we are meant to convert to upper case, then remove non-alphanumeric characters in that order but you do not state this explicitly.  Can you add this, please?

Comment: @Alchymist I believe that the instructions are clear as they are, please prove your point by providing an example to input that do not work with the rules.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman you state that the only actions you can take are to convert the case of characters and to delete characters but you do not specify that these have to be in a specific order.  Then your 'good conversion' instructions do not state when to delete characters either. 
By your example A2+b -> A2+B -> A2B (deletion occurs after capitalisation).  However equally valid is A2+b -> A2b (deletion occurs before capitalisation).

Comment: @Alchymist the good conversion speaks about the final result, based on the input. If your input is a2+b, than b is expected to become capital in the final output. In your second example you are doing legal string manipulations and then applying the conversion, in this case the conversion is not valid.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman.  Your instructions do not state when deletions should happen.  Unless you specify that then my second example is valid according to your instructions, even if it is not what you intended.  A2b is a Java style string according to your definition.

This could just be a language problem as I suspect English is not your first language.  However both I and Peter Taylor find the current rules difficult to follow.  It might be useful if you just try restating the instructions in other words.

Comment: @Alchymist how about now?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman.  I think it works, although it would still be simpler to explicitly state when to delete non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Java <del>551</del> 490 bytes

```java
public class A{public static void main(String...a){String b="";for(int i=0;i<2;i++){String[]c=a[0].split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");if(c[0].length()>0&&Character.isDigit(c[0].charAt(0)))c[0]=c[0].replaceFirst("[0-9]+","");b="";for(String d:c){boolean e=false;String f="";byte[]g=d.getBytes();for(byte h:g){if(e){if(Character.isLowerCase(h))e=false;else h+='a'-'A';}else if(!Character.isLowerCase(h))e=true;f+=(char)h;}d=f;if(d.length()>0)b+=StringUtils.capitalize(d);}a[0]=b;}System.out.println(b);}}
```

Ungolfed Code:

```java
public class A{
    public static void main(String...args){
        String input = args[0];

        String className = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String[] names = input.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
            if(names[0].length() > 0 && Character.isDigit(names[0].charAt(0))){
                names[0] = names[0].replaceFirst("[0-9]+", "");
            }
            className = "";
            for (String value : names) {
                boolean toLowerCase = false;
                String newValue = "";
                byte[] bytes = value.getBytes();
                for (byte aByte : bytes) {
                    if(toLowerCase){
                        if (Character.isLowerCase(aByte)){
                            toLowerCase = false;
                        }
                        else{
                            aByte += 'a' - 'A';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!Character.isLowerCase(aByte)){
                        toLowerCase = true;
                    }
                    newValue += (char)aByte;
                }

                value = newValue;
                if(value.length() > 0){
                    className += StringUtils.capitalize(value);
                }
            }
            input = className;
        }


        System.out.println(className);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell 316 bytes

Not fully golfed, may spend time to golf a bit more if others come and join the game.

```
import Data.Char
data T = C | S | X
conv t [] = []
conv t (c:cs)
  |isLower c = case t of X -> toUpper c : conv C cs; _ -> c : conv S cs
  |isUpper c = case t of C -> toLower c : conv X cs; _ -> c : conv C cs
  |isDigit c = c : conv S cs
  |otherwise = conv X cs
main = interact $ conv X . dropWhile isDigit . conv X
```

The C, S, X, `data = T = C | S | X` stands for Capital, Small, Other.